# Locating the function definition of a function

Tags: c++, function, sfml

I'm new and getting into programming so I apologize if this has already been answered or explained. Basically, I've been looking in the documentation of the SFML library and come across some sf::Font class public member functions. One for example is this:

```
bool sf::Font::loadFromFile  ( const std::string &  filename )
```

Following that is what the function does:

```
/// \brief Load the font from a file
///
/// The supported font formats are: TrueType, Type 1, CFF,
/// OpenType, SFNT, X11 PCF, Windows FNT, BDF, PFR and Type 42.
/// Note that this function know nothing about the standard
/// fonts installed on the user's system, thus you can't
/// load them directly.
///
/// \warning SFML cannot preload all the font data in this
/// function, so the file has to remain accessible until
/// the sf::Font object loads a new font or is destroyed.
///
/// \param filename Path of the font file to load
///
/// \return True if loading succeeded, false if it failed
///
/// \see loadFromMemory, loadFromStream
///
```

I've downloaded the library and looked inside the header files but I can't seem to find how the loadFromFile function actually accomplishes the loading (In other words, I'd be looking for a function body or a **function definition** that does the work). The documentation only explains **what** the function does, not **how**.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or something that should be apparent. I'm just extremely curious about where the core of the function is.

By the way, [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Font.php#ab020052ef4e01f6c749a85571c0f3fd1) is an exact link to the page and section of the documentation I'm referring to.

Thank you to anyone who answers.

Comment: The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) has a search function that should lead you to the code. Googling "library_name source code" usually works for these kinds of issues.

Comment: Take a look at [github repo](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Font.cpp) which has function definitions....

Comment: Thank you. I realize now I overlooked the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for can be found in the public Github repository.

It's in the file Font.cpp starting on line 122:

https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Font.cpp#L122

Documentation will not mention this because the documentation is about the behavior the user of this function can rely on. How a method achieves this behavior is a private implementation detail that the user should not need to know.

Comment: Thank you. I've realized that the private implementation that you mentioned is included in the source code, which should not be publicly available to any one user (eg. for purposes of reverse engineering). My understanding may be a little off, but it's basically meant to be hidden so that it can't be tampered with (where the source code is not available). Or to protect against unintentional mistakes with the core of the app/code.